How to escape both single quotes and exclamation marks in bash
I have a long command and I just want to use alias to shorten it. But the command contains single quotes and exclamation marks.
The origin command is ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc!123'.
I tried alias search='ldapsearch -x -H ... -w \'abc!123\'' or alias search="ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc!123'" and so on. But none of them works for me.

! is only a problem for history expansion. History expansion only happens in interactive shells (when not disabled altogether by the user like I do) and in bash (like in zsh, but contrary to csh where both history expansion and aliases come from) happens before alias expansion and is not done again after aliases are expanded, so it's fine to leave a ! unquoted in the value of an alias:
alias search='ldapsearch -x -H ... -w abc!123'

That alias command will be fine even if run in an interactive shell because in bash (again like in zsh but contrary to csh), single quotes prevent !, ^... from triggering history expansion.
To have the ! single quoted in the value of the alias, you'd have to do things like:
alias search='ldapsearch -x -H ... -w '\'abc\!123\'
alias search=$'ldapsearch -x -H ... -w \'abc!123\''
alias search='ldapsearch -x -H ... -w '\''abc!123'\'
alias search="ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc"\!"123'"
alias search=ldapsearch\ -x\ -H\ ...\ -w\ \'abc\!123\'

That is make sure the ! is quoted by either '...', $'...' or \ (outside of any other form of quotes) not double quotes.
Using "abc!123" works in non-interactive shells, but not in interactive ones. "abc\!123" work in interactive ones but not non-interactive ones.
Instead of an alias, you can use a function (aliases got popular because they appeared in csh (circa 1979) before the Bourne shell added functions (circa 1983), but they're really a wart in the face of shells these days).
search() { ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc!123' "$@"; }

Or even possibly better, make it a:
#! /bin/sh -
exec ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc!123' "$@"

Then you'll be able to call it from anywhere, not just your interactive shells.
Now passing a password on the command line is very bad practice as command line arguments are public information on most systems. They show up in the output of ps -f, they are stored in shell histories or audit log.
Instead you should use something like:
search() {
  ldapsearch -x -H ... -y ~/.config/secrets/ldap/host.password "$@"
}

With ~/.config/secrets/ldap/host.password being readable only to yourself and containing the password, or:
search() {
  ldapsearch -x -H ... -y <(
    command-that-retrieves-the-password from your password manager
  )  "$@"
}


Storing the password in your alias might pose security implications. I would suggest you to use a function and have the password parametrized as follows. For example
ldap_search() {
    local password="$1"
    ldapsearch -x -H ... -w "$password"
} 

Then you'd source your bashrc file
source ~/.bashrc

Then use the function as follows:
ldap_search "<Paste here your password>"

Hint: You can also use read -s -p 'Enter password: ' password  so the password doesn't appear in your history file.

If you "paste your password" and it contains ! characters (or `"$``) it will fails as history substitution is still done inside single quotes.

The OP will still likely want to pass more arguments to ldapsearch like the search filter, base, scope, list of attributes to return. I think the OP's point of using an alias is that he doesn't have to enter the password each time.

ldapsearch will safely prompt for the bind password if you use -W instead of -w secret, that read command will not work properly if the password contains backslash of characters of $IFS.

You are right. In this case -W flag would be a better choice. I also do agree with the rest of arguments but that's where the ... dots were for :). the -w or -W could be placed anywhere.  Thanks for the comments

I mean they'll want to use search -b ou=people sn=Liu givenName for instance.

I know the difference and security issues between -W and -w secret. But the key point of my question is how to use single quotes and exclamation marks in alias correctly. The ldapsearch is just an example of such case. So I will vote up the answer from @StéphaneChazelas. But thanks all the same.

History Expansion is only relevant when using bash interactively.
Switching to single quotes is not always sensible.Escaping Exclamation Marks without using single quotes is strange and adds nicely to the quote in quote inceptions of bash:
You can use !"" instead of ! because "" inside double quotes is nothing and !" is not a history expansion since bash 4.3.

$>A="git commit -m "Frustrating !"" Its dark outside in $(date +%B)"; make" ; echo $A;

git commit -m "Frustrating ! Its dark outside in November"; make




bash -c $A


or a char not followed by a dynamic string b:

$>b='b' ; echo "abac" | grep -P ".(?!""$b)"

abac (#negative lookahead)


interactive alias setting:

$> alias ldapsearch="ldapsearch -x -H ... -w 'abc!""123'"

.. with an extra space at the beginning to at least prevent committing the password to the bash history. Please see the other answers concerning passwords.
